# Using UIView as SCNPlane contents causes weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to use any `UIView` as contents of `SCNPlane diffuse geometry` in `SceneKit` session. It works fine sometimes, but it is causing weird behavior other times. When I add a node to the scene, this `view` is presented flat on the screen like it was just added as a `subview` to `ViewController` view. Just sits in the left upper corner, instead of being presented on the `node` that contains this `plane`. And after few seconds or after rotating the screen it most of the time is moved to the plane and work as expected. This doesn't happened when I add `views layer` instead of `view`, but I need to work with view to get touches working.

```
extension UIView: FindloMedia {

    func getMediaNode(augmentedRealityView: AugmentedRealityViewBase) -> Any {
        let viewGeometry = SCNPlane()
        viewGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = self
        viewGeometry.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = true
        return SCNNode(geometry: viewGeometry)
    }

}
```

...
View is created in such a way:

```
let view = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Zrzut ekranu 2018-08-19 o 14.36.26.png"))
```

I tested for thread used, and all is happening on main thread.

Comment: Mapping a UIView onto a SceneKit material is best done only when you need complex subview structure or interactive functionality. If all you need is to map an image onto a material, don't use UIImageView, set the material's contents directly to your PNG image (that is, a UIImage object loaded from that PNG).

Comment: UIImageView was just an example. Finally I would like to use WebView